# Do these two async functions run in parallel?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

Let's say we have two async functions like so:

```
const getUrl = async () => ...logic

const getName = async () => ...logic
```

and then I want to define an object which the values of the keys are these functions such as:

```
const defineObject = async() => {

   const obj = {
      url: await getUrl()
      name: await getName()
   }
}
```

Is this going to behave as generally JS does where it waits for the first async function to run `getUrl()` and then runs the second async function `getName()`, or, does it run them in parallel.

Comment: No, they will not run in parallel. If you use the `await` keyword it will wait thus not continue starting any other tasks in parallel.

Comment: This "magic" is a syntactic sugar to using callbacks or promises instead

Comment: You can use `Promise.all` to run multiple promises in paralel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they won't run in parallel. Each use of `await` turns into a `getXXX().then()`, with the code after it put into the `.then()` callback function.

If you want to do that, you can use `Promise.all()`.

```
const [url, name] = await Promise.all([getUrl(), getName()]);
const obj = {url, name};
```

Comment: Perfect, that is what I thought but wasn't 100% sure if in this scenario things could be different. Thank you :)